# How to remove leftover icons from notification area?

Tags: windows, icons

The notification area, when I customize it, still shows three programs and their icons. But they can not be seen if I customize to show them. They are not possible to remove from the list.
The programs are uninstalled, the registry cleaned, no leftovers there. So... how to remove these icons from the list for the  tray after the programs are removed? Once again, the registry is also clean! Where are those icons/info hiding?

Answer (score 2):

This article explains how to do it:

### [How to Clear Customize Notifications (System Tray) Icons in Windows 7/Vista and XP](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/clear-customize-notifications-tray-items-windows-7-vista-xp/)

To clear the Customize Notifications items list manually, follow the steps below:

1. Click Start, type regedit.exe and
   press {Enter}
2. Navigate to the following branch:

   [Windows XP]

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Explorer \ TrayNotify
   ```

   [Windows 7 & Windows Vista]

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Classes \ Local Settings \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ TrayNotify
   ```
3. Delete the two values namely
   `IconStreams` and `PastIconsStream`
4. Exit the Registry Editor
5. Terminate Windows Explorer / Shell
   cleanly. [Instructions for [Windows XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffdav/archive/2004/07/22/191636.aspx) / [Windows Vista, Windows 7](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-terminate-and-restart-explorerexe-process-cleanly-in-windows-7-and-vista/)]

**Script to Automate**

Here is a VBScript (runs in Windows XP/Vista/7) that can automate the above task for you. Download [clear-notification-items.zip](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/clear-notification-items.zip), unzip and run `clear-notification-items.vbs` file. It clears Customize Notifications items and restarts Explorer shell automatically.

Comment: Dang, I was too slow!

Comment: @Moab: Wild wild west! ;)

Answer (score 0):

just being helpful, soooo much quicker here !
One click does it!
:):)

copy, save as .vbs

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/winhelponline/2587aaa1d2b32c61124f4c6f0d4eac67/raw/1844d5f0cdf76f22290904b002c72ada5deac27f/clear_notification_taskbar_overflow_icons.vbs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192908)