# How to remove uninstalled programs from Notification Area

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, notification-area

For some reason I had 2 instances of Apache running, and I have no idea how. I also had two instances of ApacheMonitor.exe showing in the "Notification Area Icons" place when you right click on your taskbar and go to properties. To fix the multiple instance issue, I deleted Apache completely and uninstalled the service (I did not use the .msi, I install from a .zip). Anyways, Everything from Apache is gone except the two things in the Notification Area Icon page. Does anyone know how to remove these two icons? I have completely uninstalled Apache, cleaned my registry with CCleaner, and rebooted. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

[image]

Despite what the picture says, I do NOT have Apache installed, and it is not running.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/266065/how-to-remove-leftover-icons-from-notification-area?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using CCleaner to clean 'Icon Notification Area', closed explorer.exe in Task Manager, restarted explorer.exe.